# Returning pairs of values

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

I'm using a large amount of grid-based pathfinding in my project, and thus, I created a class to save pairs of x,y values, but as I didn't want to go around instancing objects to save the pairs of values, I'm simply storing normal doubles in pairs, so I know that if I always store and retrieve them by pairs, I won't have any problem. Now, I also want the classes using this Path structure to give and receive the values in pairs. To give the values I would just use parameters, and it'll work just fine, but to retrieve the values I don't know how to do it. In C++ normally I would do a "return by reference":

```
void getNextPointInPath(float& x, float& y) {
    //And I set x and y to be the next pair of values in the 
}
```

But I'm stuck in how to do it java, as the whole point of this is to not be instancing classes to return them every time I call the getter method, I can't use a class which contains a float to pass around so I'll be able to simulate a pass by reference (And I mean simulate, not actually do. I know passing by reference is impossible in java) so is there any nice way to do this in Java?

EDIT: I read this again and maybe I didn't explain myself clear enough. When I say pairs I mean one after another, I'm actually using a LinkedList< Float> to store the points.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to create a new object to represent the pair of values?

Comment: Because that would mean that the class using Path class also has to know about this new data structure, and that would also mean that I would need to be instancing objects with new in order to return them, when I just need to return two single values.

Of course i could create some general class like the Pair in C++, but the whole point of this was to make the Path class easy to use, and I don't feel returning custom objects is the best way. Maybe it's just because I'm still thinking in C++ and not in Java.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it's a matter of not thinking in Java. If you want to return a pair of values, encapsulate them in an object.

Comment: Well, I'll go with is for now, I just don't like using classes for even the simplest thing. As it makes the classes using some helper class like Path have to know and use another class (maybe FloatPair).

And it might not be a matter of not thinking in java, but I have been taught to work in C++ and I'm learning Java mostly by trial and error. So I'm clearly thinking how would I do it in C++ and trying to translate that.

Comment: It shouldn't be a "FloatPair" - it should be a "Point" - that's what you're trying to represent, after all. The key is in your method name - get next **Point** in path.

Comment: You're completely right with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you've actually tried creating a new object to return from the method each time. That would be my first attempt - if you're worried about the performance, you can tackle that when you've actually proved it's a problem. Create an immutable `Point` class (probably with `equals` and `hashCode` overridden for testing purposes - but beware of normal floating point issues) and an overridden `toString` method. It'll be pretty short, and should be your universal way of representing a point. Then your method signature looks a lot more sensible:

```
public Point getNextPointOnPath() {
    ...
}
```

Any time you write a *get* method which has a `void` return type, you should be worried.

The next option would be to create a *mutable* type containing a pair of floats. Pass a reference to an existing object in, and let the method mutate the object.

Finally, you could return a `long` which contained the bit pattern of the two `float` values. (Use `Float.floatToIntBits` on each `float`, and use one as the top 32 bits and one as the bottom 32 bits of the `long`.) But that's horrible, and it wouldn't work for larger data types.

Comment: Although your bitwise idea sounds fun to implement, that wouldn't solve my problem as the classes using Path would be even more implementation-dependant.

Aside from that, yes, I thought on creating a method to store pairs of floats, but I just wanted to know if there's a way that doesn't involve creating a new data structure just to hold two floats.

Comment: A simple immutable class holding two floats will have a negligible performance impact and will make your code clearer.

Comment: @Setzer22: You still haven't presented any reason not to create such a class other than that you don't feel like it...

Comment: Is this mutable/immutable thing a concept or is there really some kind of keyword to make a class mutable/immutable? Because if I don't declare any setter methods, I would just have a class being immutable woudldn't I?

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I said that I don't like to be instancing objects to return them. And yes, I know that with modern computers this is negligible, but aside from that, I don't like the class using Path having to know how to use another class, it's just that. Of course I can go with the object sollution, I figured that out myself after asking. I was just asking if there was a better way to do this in Java and it seems there's not.

Comment: "I don't like" is basically like "you don't feel like it". It's not a good engineering decision. And it's entirely natural for `Path` to need to know about other types which are clearly relevant to its domain - such as a `Point`. As for immutability - use `final` fields, make the class `final`, and just populate the fields in the constructor. Add `get` methods and you're away.